# Entity Framework Adding new record with foreign key constraint

Tags: c#, entity-framework

In an effort to learn the entity framework I have created two tables in a one to many relationship.  The one table (Author) has the following fields - AuthorID, FirstName, LastName.  The many table (Payroll) has the following fields - PayrollID, AuthorID, Salary.  I have CRUD stored procdures for insert, update and delete.  What I am tying to figure-out is how to add new payroll records to the payroll table.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem I decided to move my code to Entity Framework 4 where I can have the model generate foreign key relationships.  Thanks to all.